# Why doesn't nn.Sequential contain a softmax output layer in the example?

Tags: pytorch

The example from [PyTorch's official tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nn_tutorial.html) has the following ConvNet. My understanding is that the output layer uses a softmax to estimate the digit an image corresponds to. Why doesnt the code have a softmax layer or fully connected layer?

```
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(16, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(16, 10, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1),
    Lambda(lambda x: x.view(x.size(0), -1)),
)

opt = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr, momentum=0.9)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question! The reason why no fully-connected layer is used is because of a technique called Global Average Pooling, implemented via `nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)`. The benefits of this operation over fc layers were introduced in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04150.pdf), including reducing the number of model parameters while preserving performance, acting as a regulariser, and modelling deep localisation information. GAP can be used in place of fc, as well as before a subsequent fc layer.

As for why there is no softmax layer, I think that this is because they use the `CrossEntropyLoss` loss function in the backend. This function takes in raw logits and combines `nn.LogSoftmax()` and `nn.NLLLoss()` in one computation. So there is no need to perform an additional softmax function before loss evaluation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Can you also give me an idea how dimensionality works out in the convolution? Before the last convolution, the model has 16 channels. How does the last convolution change it to 10 channels?

Comment: This is because in `nn.Conv2d(16, 10, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)`, 16 represents the `in_channels` while 10 is the `out_channels`

Comment: How does convolution transform an input of 16 channels to 10? Shouldn't it preserve the number of input channels?

Comment: Not at all. The number of output channels depends on the number of filters you use (ie. `out_channels`), because convolution essentially computes the dot product between the input feature map and the filter spatially, and stacks all these maps depth-wise to transform the number of channels. Hope this resolves your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This network structure relaced the fully connected layer with global average pooling.
Classical network structure model [Network in Network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4400) use this.